# How to replace the initial form of an Arabic letter using PHP?

Tags: php, replace, character-encoding, arabic, unicode-string

I have an Arabic text and want to replace "Initial" & "Medial" forms of some letters (not all forms) with other letters or characters;

Example:

```
$text = '...وقد تم تصميم وبناء جميع مكونات الطائرة';
```

I need to replace the Initial form of letter "ت" which is in the word "تم" with another letter; available "ت" in "مكونات" that is the Final form of this letter shall not be replaced.

It seems character codes (Unicode) cannot be used in `str_replace()` to find a specific form of a letter and replace it.

Note:

Most Arabic letters have different froms:

- Initial form: used in the start of a word, like "ت" in "تم".
- Medial form: used in the middle of a word, like "ت" in "نستعين".
- Final form: used in the last of a word, like "ت" in "مكونات".

see [wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet#Table_of_basic_letters) for more information.

Comment: Love that question :)

Comment: The "letter forms" of Arabic lettering is probably not well known, and most readers may need more of an explanation. [This is useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet#Letter_forms).

Answer (score 0):

Here i have given piece of code..hope will work for you``` $text = '...وقد تم تصميم وبناء جميع مكونات الطائرة';
$a=array('ت','تم');
$b=array('ت','مكونات');``
echo str_replace($a,$b,$text); ```

Answer (score -1):

Letter forms are used for output only. They shouldn't be stored and/or manipulated in this way. You should find another way to do what you want.

Try RegExp.
This might help you. http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Or, if you insist on using `str_replace`, you can do this.

```
str_replace(
  ' ت',
  ' وت',
  $string
);
```